# Update value with Sencha Touch / Ext JS localstorage duplicated entries

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, local-storage, store

i want to update a value of an record in my localstorage. At the moment it will be added a new record with the same id, duplicated. For example if the function update will be executed the row that contains all the ids (here 'test-proxy') then it will be appended the same id again.

```
model.Test = Ext.regModel('model.Test', {
    idProperty: 'id',
fields : [ {
    name : 'id',
    type : 'integer'
}, {
    name : 'name',
    type : 'string'
}
]});


//Store
store = new Ext.data.Store({
model : 'model.Test',
sorters : 'title',
storeId : 'test',
 proxy: {
    type: 'localstorage',
    id  : 'test-proxy',
    idProperty: 'id'
}
});

updateName = function(id) {
    store.read();
    var item = store.getAt(id-1).data;

    //toggle
    item.name = "Update"
    store.add(item);
    store.sync();
    console.log(store.getAt(id-1));
}
```

Comment: ok the problem i have looks more to be an cache or reload issue. Because if i reload the page everything is fine. The problem is that the old (not updated) data are still in the Ext.DataView. After page reload by browser only the updated items will be listed.

Answer (score 2):

OK I found the solution for that problem. The problem is related to refreshing the DataView.

```
store.load();
listData.refresh(); // will refresh  Ext.DataView
```